# SharePoint 2010: Sync name change from AD to SharePoint. Set-SPUser : Cannot get the full name or e-mail address of user

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2010

Typical use case is when someone gets married and their username is changed in active directory (AD).  Each site collection has a list of users which are updated by an AD/SharePoint sync task, but it doesn't work well when a user's name changes. These command list all the problem site collections:

```
Get-SPWebApplication -Identity $Url | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RootWeb | Get-SPUser -Limit All | Where {$_.LoginName -like  $OldLoginName} | select Name, LoginName, ParentWeb
```

These command usually fixes the problem:

```
Get-SPWebApplication -Identity $Url | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RootWeb | Get-SPUser -Limit All | Where {$_.DisplayName -eq $OldDisplayName -or $_.LoginName -eq $OldLoginName} | Set-SPUser -SyncFromAD
```

I'm getting following error.

```
Set-SPUser : Cannot get the full name or e-mail address of user
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

running this script fixed the problem

```
stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin $oldLogin -newlogin $newlogin -ignoresidhistory
```